# Удалить использование unsafe кода

Tags: c#, .net, unsafe

Возможно ли переписать метод без использование unsafe кода?

```
public static void ReplaceM(MethodBase src, MethodBase dest)
{
    unsafe
    {
        IntPtr srcAdr = new IntPtr(((int*)src.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 12));
        IntPtr destAdr = new IntPtr(((int*)dest.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 12));

        if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
        {
            ulong* d = (ulong*)destAdr.ToPointer();
            *d = *((ulong*)srcAdr.ToPointer());
        }
        else
        {
            uint* d = (uint*)destAdr.ToPointer();
            *d = *((uint*)srcAdr.ToPointer());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно через маршал `System.Runtime.InterpropServices.Marshal`

```
Marshal.WriteIntPtr(destAdr,Marshal.ReadIntPtr(srcAdr));
```

Пересмещать destAdr - это куча ненужных преобразований, маршал поддерживает смещение, поэтому, проще будет так (т.е. код ниже заменит всю процедуру)

```
Marshal.WriteIntPtr(dest.MethodHandle.Value,48,
 Marshal.ReadIntPtr(src.MethodHandle.Value,48));
```

С взятием адреса обьекта чуть сложнее (может пригодится)

```
 var g = GCHandle.Alloc(obj);
   g.ToIntPtr(); // Взятие адреса
 g.Free();
```

Последствия правда могут быть непредсказуемы, как и при unsafe.

P.S. Замена тела метода... возможно вам нужен делегат [Вики делегат](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%29) (переменная с ссылкой на метод)

Comment: Эта строка, как я понял, меняет местами в памяти destAdr и srcAdr?

Comment: А как получить destAdr, srcAdr из dest/src.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer()? Т.е. аналог первых двух строчек.

Comment: Много мороки с преобразованием, я не обратил сразу внимание, проще будет 12 в Read/Write

Comment: ToPointer() все равно требует директивы unsafe

Comment: А вам точно он нужен? По-моему его можно убрать и всё. Ведь IntPtr не надо в Pointer преобразовывать.

Comment: Не знаю, может Pointer  не нужен. На смещении 12 все работает, а вот при смещении 2 ошибка. Причем при использовании поинтера со смещением 2 все хорошо

Comment: Не заработало, к сожалению. То есть код отрабаывает но изменений нет. Нашел немного другое решение.

Comment: Увидел решение. Смещение в байтах, поэтому надо не 12 а 48 в ReadIntPtr и т п.

Comment: Ага, именно так.

Answer (score 0):

Вот нашел еще вариант.

```html
var srcAdr = src.MethodHandle.Value + 48;
var dstAdr = dest.MethodHandle.Value + 48;

var buffer = new byte[IntPtr.Size];

Marshal.Copy(srcAdr, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, dstAdr, buffer.Length);
```